# Solve the initial value problem $xyy' + xy' = 1$ and $y(1) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I can solve the differential equation, which is $y + y^{2}/2 = \ln(x) + C$.

But I cannot solve the IVP because I can't isolate for $y$ and find the value of $C.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Merajhaq: **Hint:** get the equation in the form $(y+1)^2 = ...$ and then isolate $y$,

Comment: Why would you need to isolate y to solve for $C$. $0 + \dfrac{0^2}{2}=\ln(1)+C$.

Comment: But you do need to be careful, because only one of the two roots of the quadratic satisfies the initial condition.

Answer (score 3):

We have (just reproducing your work for completeness, and combining some of the comment ideas):
\begin{align*}
xyy'+xy'&=1\\
xy'(y+1)&=1\\
(y+1)\,dy&=\frac{dx}{x}\\
\frac{y^2}{2}+y&=\ln(x)+C\\
0&=\ln(1)+C\\
0&=C\\
\frac{y^2}{2}+y&=\ln(x)\\
y^2+2y&=2\ln(x)\\
y^2+2y+1&=2\ln(x)+1\\
(y+1)^2&=2\ln(x)+1\\
y+1&=\pm\sqrt{2\ln(x)+1}\\
y&=-1\pm\sqrt{2\ln(x)+1}.
\end{align*}
But notice that we can't allow the negative square root, because it doesn't actually satisfy the initial condition. Also notice that we threw out the $\ln|x|$ for $\ln(x),$ because we knew the initial condition would be for positive $x.$ So the final solution is
$$y=-1+\sqrt{2\ln(x)+1}. $$